# Kotlin android studio I try to change the button text but get an "exepected a value of type boolean" message

Tags: android, kotlin

Kotlin in Android Studio. I'm trying to change the button text but I'm getting an **"exepected a value of type boolean"** message. How can I fix this?

```
    button11.setOnLongClickListener{
        button11.text = ""
    }
```

Comment: Show the full code please.

Answer (score 6):

The [`onLongClick`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html#onLongClick(android.view.View)) method in the `View.OnLongClickListener` interface that you're implementing here via SAM conversion returns a `boolean` value, signaling whether you've consumed the long click event.

Therefore, you need to return a `Boolean` from your lambda in Kotlin, for example, like this (the last expression of a lambda is returned):

```
button11.setOnLongClickListener {
    button11.text = ""
    true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using not null or safe :

```
button11?.setOnLongClickListener{
    button?.text=""
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the lambda must return a boolean